# Как очистить все поля компонентов?

Tags: delphi

У меня на форме расположено примерно 50 Edit'ов , 121 label и 36 Combobox . Как программно очистить их значения не перебирая каждый компонент по отдельности, ведь это очень глупо получиться ?

Comment: выдели их всех, повесь на них событие и удали содержимое, оно удалится на всех элементах

Comment: Мне не по событию нужно очищать их, а под определенным условием в программе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i:=0 to Form1.ComponentCount-1 do
begin
  if (Form1.Components[i] is TEdit) then TEdit(Form1.Components[i]).Text:='';
  if (Form1.Components[i] is TCombobox) then TCombobox(Form1.Components[i]).ItemIndex:=-1;
  if (Form1.Components[i] is TLabel) then TLabel(Form1.Components[i]).Caption:='';
end;
```

Comment: В принципе работает только одно НО.
У меня на форме PageControl в них GroupBox.
И очистилось только в первом боксе, т.е. в GroupBox1. Что не так ?

Comment: Массив Components формы содержит **все** компоненты формы. Может быть другие компоненты у вас там лежат...

Comment: все разобрался, ты все правильно написал, я просто сам ошибся когда перепечатывал у меня форма 12-ая а не первая.